# How are values in a two tailed t-table calculated?

Tags: t-test

Can anyone point me to where the formula is for calculate the values that populated a t-table?

For example, I am trying to figure out how I find the critical t-table values for a unique confidence interval (say 43%)?

Comment: You can do this using simple built-in functions in Microsoft Excel.

Comment: I am looking for the actual formula though for calculating the critical values that would populate a t-table based on the given confidence interval (43% or 55% etc).

Comment: You integrate the t distribution, which means dealing with the cumulative distribution function (CDF) of the t distribution. So just look that up and have at it. But this is excellent advice: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/52358/247352 and look at the similar questions and answers here.